# operation on php or html

Tags: javascript

anyone help me, how to implementation operation ( ^ ) on excel to php ????
pls help me, cause i'm already use operation ( / ) but the value isn't not same with ^ on excel.

```
 function sum(){
  var txtFirstNumberValue =document.getElementById('bunga').value/100;
  var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('waktu').value;
  var result = (1+txtFirstNumberValue);
  var ambil = parseFloat(result);
  hasil = ambil/parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue);
  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    parseFloat(document.getElementById('pf').value = hasil);
  }
```

}

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Why would you use the `/` operator to do the `^` operation? Why not use `^`?

Comment: @mods I think the PHP and HTML tags should be removed from this question. Seems like strictly a JavaScript issue; maybe Excel as well.

Comment: thank guys, already fix this problemmmm,,, i have used math.pow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript the caret or `^` operator is not an exponent operator, it is instead a [Bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR) operator. If you need to perform exponentiation use `Math.pow()` where `Math.pow(a, b)` is the same as *a<sup>b</sup>*.